# Spring DataJPA @ManyToOne Uidirectional N+1 problem

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Haven't played in a while with Hibernate's @OneToMany and @ManytoOne.
Let's take the following example. We have table book and one called page. I'm only interested in pages content (and book details within the page)

Page:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "page")
public class Page {
   @Id
   @Column
   private String id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", nullable = false)
   private Book book;
}
```

Book:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @Column
    private String book_id;

    @Column
    private String details;
}
```

Then I need to extract all pages, using spring data;

```
pageRepo.findAll();
```

It works but I ran into N+1 problem. Having N+1 selects. Is there a way to solve this, but keeping the relation unidirectional?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a QUERY into your Crud/Jpa Repository where you explicitly use JOIN between Page and Book

Something like this:

```
public interface PageRepository extends JpaRepository<Page, String> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Page p JOIN Book b ON p.book_id = b.id")
    List<Page> findAll();
}
```

Comment: Sounds good, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Same result. Multumesc ;)

Comment: Solved it with the following query
@Query("SELECT p from Page p JOIN FETCH Book b on p.book")